# How to encode ampersand in URL with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, urlencode, ampersand

I have some URLs being dynamically output onto a div which contain an `&` like this:

```
<div id="box">
    <a href="http://domain.com/index.html&location=1">First URL</a> 
    <a href="http://domain.com/index.html&location=2">Second URL</a>
</div>
```

Is there a way - using jQuery - for every instance of `&` to be converted into the HTML entity equivalent instead, so that the output becomes this?

```
<div id="box">
    <a href="http://domain.com/index.html&amp;location=1">First URL</a> 
    <a href="http://domain.com/index.html&amp;location=2">Second URL</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You know, most (if not all) modern browsers will automatically fix the encoding for you while parsing the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#box a').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('&','&amp;'));
  });
```

Comment: `this` will reference the `window` object unless you create a closure with e.g. `.each`. Firebug is throwing a `TypeError: $(this).attr("href") is undefined` when you call the replace method on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/sACYn/1/). Any modern browser will automatically fix the url encoding when parsing the DOM though.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yes that was a serious mistake, thank you for pointing out, yes even I just put +1 for the other answer ;)

Comment: +1 for taking the time to fix that. Nice and clean answer as well. `=]`

Answer (score 2):

> This will loop through all the `a` tags that exist in the document and will replace all the special chars in the `href` attribute into html entities

```
$('a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href',htmlEncode($(this).attr('href')));
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});


function htmlEncode(value){
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ezjCr/)

---

> Looping through all the `a` tags and replacing only the & symbol:

```
$('a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href').replace('&','&amp;');
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: I'll +1 your answer as it at least wouldn't break the javascript in the page neither the links. Very well written as well.